# Concatenating variables in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have defined some powershell variables like below

```
$Host101 = "10.1.1.101"
$Host102 = "10.1.1.102"
$HDD101 = "DataStoreH101"
$HDD102 = "DataStoreH102"
$SSD101 = "DataStoreS101"
$SSD102 = "DataStoreS102"

My-Command -H $Host101 -Disk $HDD101 -Disk $SSD101
```

Now, I want to define `$Node = "101"` and then use the following command

```
My-Command -H $Host$Node -Disk $HDD$Node -Disk $SSD$Node
```

As I test `Write-Host "$HDD$Node"`, it doesn't print `DataStoreH101`. How can I write something like that in powershell?

Comment: You have not declared the `$HDD` variable? Following works for me `$HDD='HDDTest';$Node='NodeTest';"$HDD$Node"`. It prints `HDDTestNodeTest`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: Right. I got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can also `-Disk ($HDD + $Node)`. you can simply add strings together with `+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you have to also define the `$Node` variable and its value before you can use it.  I will assume you already know this and that was just an oversight left out of the question.

I've used similar PowerShell solutions to concatenate part of a variable's name to set the variable and then later have that fully concatenated variable executed using [Invoke-Expression](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-expression.html).

### PowerShell

```
$Host101 = "10.1.1.101";
$Host102 = "10.1.1.102";
$HDD101 = "DataStoreH101";
$HDD102 = "DataStoreH102";
$SSD101 = "DataStoreS101";
$SSD102 = "DataStoreS102";

$Node = "101"; ## Set the node number to concatenate to variable name before invoking it    

$cmd = "Write-Host `"-H `$Host$Node -Disk `$HDD$Node -Disk `$SSD$Node`" -ForegroundColor Green"
Invoke-Expression -Command $cmd
```

> **Script Notes**
>
> - You will need to prefix a backtick [`] character before the first part of the literal variable name that contains the literal `$` character in the `$cmd` value so it is still a literal dollar sign to be invoked and can be expanded to the full concatenated value when invoked.
> - For `My-Command` I've used [`Write-Host`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7.1)
>   so I had to put a backtick prefix before the double quotes within it
>   so at execution time the `$cmd` variable still contains those for when
>   it is invoked for the string value—be aware of this with whatever command you are using
>   with this solution as well.
> - If possible otherwise with the command you use, you could replace the inner double quotes with single quotes. Then you'd just keep the outer double quotes and not need to escape the inner single quotes with the backtick character.
> - **E.g.**
>
>   ```
>   $cmd = "Write-Host '-H `$Host$Node -Disk `$HDD$Node -Disk `$SSD$Node' -ForegroundColor Green"
>   ```

### Output Examples

Running `$cmd` outputs this

```
Write-Host "-H $Host101 -Disk $HDD101 -Disk $SSD101" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Running `Invoke-Expression -Command $cmd;` outputs this (in green of course)

```
-H 10.1.1.101 -Disk DataStoreH101 -Disk DataStoreS101
```

### PowerShell ISE output with screen shot annotations

[image]

### Supporting Resources

- [Invoke-Expression](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-expression.html)

Comment: @mahmood There you go, let me know how it goes. There might be a different way to do this as well but I've always had great success saving the concatenated variable to another variable and then invoking that variable with `invoke-expression`

Comment: Thanks. it also works.